# Double boot choice

Tags: grub2, bootloader

I am keeping in my system both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. Initially I had **Grub2** as boot loader. Afterward I swapped back to the Windows Boot-loader, adding an entry for Linux through **EasyBCD**.

Now, when I start the computer, the Windows boot loader asks for a choice between Windows and Linux. After having selected Linux, the previous Grub2 loader comes in asking which system I would like to start. So is there a way to *avoid that grub2* prompts again which system to boot, automatically loading Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the GRUB timeout to 0.

First, type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` in the terminal.  Enter your password and a window will appear.

Locate this line: `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` or something similar to that.

Change `10` to `0`.  Now the line should look like this: `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`

Then save the file and close the window.  Last, type `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Done!